# Sqrt and Pow in Cassandra NoSQL (Nearest neighbor)

Tags: cassandra, maps, nosql

Is there any way to use this Math functions in Cassandra NoSQL? I found the function below while looking for a way to get the nearest row given a latitude and longitude.

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, sqrt(
    pow(69.1 * (latitude - [startlat]), 2) +
    pow(69.1 * ([startlng] - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM TableName HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Math functions are not built in to CQL, but there is a new feature in Cassandra 2.2 called user defined functions which allow you to create math functions.  I'm not sure if you can use the result of the math operation to restrict the rows returned.

Here is an example:

```
cqlsh> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fLog (input double) CALLED ON NULL INPUT RETURNS double LANGUAGE java AS 'return Double.valueOf(Math.log(input.doubleValue()));';
```

See more details [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDF.html).

Probably the more common way to do this is outside of CQL where you would do a map/reduce type operation to map rows to distances and reduce it to the distances less than 25.  That could be done using Spark or programmatically with a Cassandra java client, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I searched about other ways to achieve what I want and found out that SOLR can fetch the nearest location. I'm still trying to install the Enterprise edition of datastax though. Thanks again.